# Json parse in Typescript - Next.js v14 React

Tags: json, parsing, next.js

I have a little problem for Parse JSON in Typescript using Next.js / React.

My currently code :

```
            if (mapItem.text === "") {
              customIcon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: categorieItem.icon,
                iconSize: [50, 50],
              })
            } else {
              const parsedIconData = JSON.parse(mapItem.text)
              if (parsedIconData.text != "") {
                customIcon = L.divIcon({
                  html: `<div>${parsedIconData.text}</div>`,
                  className: "custom-icon-with-text"
                  iconSize: [50, 50],
                })
              } else {
                customIcon = L.icon({
                  iconUrl: parsedIconData.icon,
                  iconSize: [parsedIconData.size, parsedIconData.size],
                })
              }
            }
```

Error :

```
Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
const parsedIconData: any (to parsedIconData)
Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
var JSON: JSON (to JSON.parse())
```

All data is on database, i use "mapItem." for get this element. My "text" element is nullable, string and JSON type.

Thank's,